# gdal.Polygonize python Sentinel-1

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-1

I am trying to process SENTINEL-1 GRD data using python and gdal. I want to get the shapefile from the input data. 
I have tried to use gdal.Open() using the following extensions but nothing seems to work:

S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20150109T163157_20150109T163222_004097_004F52_6A00.SAFE/manifest.safe
S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20150109T163157_20150109T163222_004097_004F52_6A00.SAFE
S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20150109T163157_20150109T163222_004097_004F52_6A00.tif
S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20150109T163157_20150109T163222_004097_004F52_6A00.zip

```
gdal.UseExceptions()
srs = osr.SpatialReference()

src_ds = gdal.Open( "S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20150109T163157_20150109T163222_004097_004F52_6A00.SAFE" )
if src_ds is None:
    print 'Cannot open %s' % src_filename
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
except RuntimeError, e:
    print 'Band ( %i ) not found' % band_num
    print e
    sys.exit(1)

dst_layername = "output"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = srs )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
```

Does anyone know how to handle these data using gdal?

Best,
Elisavet

Comment: hm, I can open the `measurement/*.tiff` files with gdalinfo ... so I guess it **should** be working like that.

Comment: The files are not warped yet, but have only GCPs, so Polygonizing may need one extra warping step. But you should be able to open them ...

Comment: I checked and it fails at the last step: gdal.Polygonize(srcband, None, dst_layer, 0, [],callback=None ). @RoVo like which warping step could be missing?

Comment: I don't know in Python, in the command line it would be a simple `gdalwarp srcfile dstfile`, maybe `-t_srs EPSG:...` is needed.